# Pandas MultiIndex with None values

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a MultiIndex, with data coming from a database.  Some of the values that I want to use as keys are null.  I have found this results in the data being omitted.  E.g.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys

print(sys.version)  # 3.7.3
print(pd.__version__) # 1.0.3
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A', 'a'), ('A', 'b'), ('B', 'a'), ('B', ' '), ('C', 'a'), ('C', None), ('D', '')], names=['Level 1', 'Level 2'])
print(idx)
d = {'X':{('A','a'):1, ('A','b'):2, ('B','a'):3, ('B',' '):4, ('C','a'): 5, ('C',None): 6, ('D',''):7},
'Y':{('A','a'):1, ('C',None): 6, ('D',''):7}
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=idx)
print(df)
```

The result is:

```
MultiIndex([('A', 'a'),
            ('A', 'b'),
            ('B', 'a'),
            ('B', ' '),
            ('C', 'a'),
            ('C', nan),
            ('D',  '')],
           names=['Level 1', 'Level 2'])
                   X    Y
Level 1 Level 2
A       a        1.0  1.0
        b        2.0  NaN
B       a        3.0  NaN
                 4.0  NaN
C       a        5.0  NaN
        NaN      NaN  NaN
D                7.0  7.0
```

My problem is the C/None row, which gives me `NaN` instead of 6.  Other blankish values (empty string, space) don't have this behavior.

Is this to be expected or do I need to configure the MultiIndex in a certain way?

Comment: what's the output format from the database? I dont think `None` is useful here, how do you index None?

Comment: @sammywemmy I was hoping for SQL-ish behaviour e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT level1, level2 FROM mydata` would treat null as a "value" to aggregate on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not safe when we have NaN in the index : [github1](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7052) [github2](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7031)

For simple fix , you can load your data to dataframe, then `fillna` and `set_index` back

Comment: Thanks @YOBEN_S for the links and proposed workaround.  I think I will instead convert my nulls to space-char at query time.